# Do you have to accommodate the length of the null-character when deciding the length of a fixed-width CHAR column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I used to think that to accommodate, say, the string `'Hello'`, would need a `CHAR(6)` column and not a `CHAR(5)` column.

---

**Side Note**

This, of course, assumes the UTF-8 encoding.

I understand that the `n` in the `CHAR(n)` refers to the number of *bytes* used in the storage and not the number of *characters*.

Regardless, the question remains relevant. Assuming a one-byte-per-character encoding system, the string `'Hello'`, in almost all languages (except a very few that use even more characters to record string lengths, for e.g. BSTR's and HLSTR's) contains a null-termination character.

---

I tried making a table with a `CHAR(5)` column and it fit the `'Hello'` string into a `CHAR(5)` column in my SQL Server 2017 database.

It turns out that one does not have to accommodate for the length of the null character while defining a fixed-length `CHAR(n)` column.

Can someone please confirm if that is the case?

I know its dead obvious from the experiment conducted, but I can't ignore the possibility that I might be missing something.

**UPDATE**

In the comments to this question, user [SMor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7926183/smor) writes:

> Nope - "n" in "char(n)" does not refer to number of bytes, it refers
>   to number of characters. Stop assuming and start READING the
>   documentation. You don't define the length to support the termination
>   character.

I'd like to point out that I read the documentation *before* posting this question. [The documentation unequivocally states on this matter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments):

> **char** [ ( n ) ] Fixed-size string data. n defines the string size in bytes and must be a value from 1 through 8,000. For single-byte
>   encoding character sets such as Latin, the storage size is n bytes and
>   the number of characters that can be stored is also n. For multibyte
>   encoding character sets, the storage size is still n bytes but the
>   number of characters that can be stored may be smaller than n. The ISO
>   synonym for **char** is **character**. For more information on
>   character sets, see [Single-Byte and Multibyte Character Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/single-byte-and-multibyte-character-sets?view=vs-2019).

It further goes on to elaborate in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) section:

> A common misconception is to think that CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n), the n
>   defines the number of characters. But in CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n) the n
>   defines the string length in **bytes** (0-8,000). n never defines numbers
>   of characters that can be stored. This is similar to the definition of
>   NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n).

Comment: Most SQL databases literals don't contain null termination characters, but if you interface from other sources (like C#), they might. So make sure to test your Hello string from your source. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626542/are-sql-strings-null-terminated

Comment: Nope - "n" in "char(n)" does not refer to number of bytes, it refers to number of _characters_. Stop assuming and start READING the documentation. You don't define the length to support the termination character.

Comment: SQL Server does not use `NUL` (all-bits-zero) to terminate strings, it uses explicit lengths for all variable-sized data types. If you pass in a string containing a `NUL`, then the engine will store it, and many T-SQL functions *will* treat that as a terminator (as they often defer to C standard library code), but it will never add it on its own.

Comment: The "length in bytes" the documentation refers to refers to the length of the string after being encoded in whatever encoding specified by the collation. It does not mean, nor is it meant to imply, that a `NUL` byte is present at the end.

Comment: Note that even in C, you can store a four-character string in a `char[4]` -- the `NUL` will be omitted if you do that. Of course, what this means is that you have four characters, not a string, and the resulting array cannot be passed to functions taking a string, but if you happened to know the size was always `4` (like, say, the engine knows when you declare a `CHAR(4)` column), you could process such character collections just fine without termination, and that's exactly what happens in the engine.